Convert from WordProcessingML CTPicture to DrawingML CTPicture?
I have documents that have pictures in them, but none of them are being identified by XWPFRun.getEmbeddedPictures(). I can, however, get a list of them with XWPFRun.getCTR().getPictList().
The problem is, I would like to use these pictures later, but I would need them to be of org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.picture.CTPicture schematype, instead of the org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture schematype.
I couldn't come up with a handy way of converting them, so my question is what would be the best route in doing so?
I have tried casting, but received an error (probably not needed but can try it again if the actual error message is needed) and setting it as an XmlObject, which didn't complain at all but didn't provide any actual results, either. There is an option for changeType() as well, but it returned the same object without any change in SchemaType.
